# How to act on output from a failed command

Tags: command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the easiest way to execute text from tail at the command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35732/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-execute-text-from-tail-at-the-command-line)

I was guessing the ouput of a command that fails to execute should be sent to stdout and hence can be piped. It seems I am wrong, so please correct me.

For example,

```
$easy_install
The program 'easy_install' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

So if I want to install with the command suggested, I tried

```
$easy_install | grep sudo | bash
```

i.e naively trying to pick out the last line and send it to the shell as a command. I even tried

```
$easy_install | tail -1 | bash
```

but get the same blurb without it doing anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Just `sudo apt-get install python-setuptools` and be done with it.

Comment: @jw013 true. But I just want to know how to pipe the output of such commands for perhaps a more productive use in the future.

Comment: Type `man xargs` to get an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of, since the line in question is a command, is:

```
`$easy_install 2>&1 | grep sudo`
```

The backticks or `$(…)` take the output of a command pipe and execute it as if you typed it, returning the output.

Please note that this command won't work if you're missing `sudo` and trying to install it. But since this is obviously Ubuntu, `sudo` is usually available. To avoid this, you might want to try your second choice:

```
`$easy_install 2>&1 | tail -n 1`
```

Try and wean yourself out of using `tail -1`, it's being replaced by the standard form `tail -n 1`. I find this hard myself, but I don't like deprecation warnings. :)

**Warning**: if `$easy_install` *exists* and you don't get this type of output, either of these commands are a **massive** security risk. You can end up executing arbitrary things. You can protect yourself by being more extravagant:

```
`$easy_install 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep '^sudo apt-get install'`
```

This discards `stdout`, and will only run anything starting with `sudo apt-get install` which limits things nicely, but is considerably more annoying than just typing `sudo apt-get install $package` yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Error output typically goes to standard error, not standard output; you can catch that by adding `2>&1`.

```
$ easy_install 2>&1 | grep sudo
```

That said, they're using a shell function to do that and I suspect a minor change to that function would allow it to ask you and then do it itself.